# ¿Como evitar volver a la pantalla de Login una vez logueado en Angular?

Tags: angular

Estoy necesitando ayuda, he hecho un login, lo hace correctamente y guardo la información en el sessionStorage pero cuando vuelvo atrás me aparece la pantalla login o si busco por url también hace lo mismo. Mi pregunta es, si alguien sabe ¿Cómo evitar esa forma hasta que el usuario cierre sesión?

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: La forma más apropiada es usando "guard" a los componentes. En los guard retorna un booleano en donde se puede acceder a la ruta para casos en los cuales la ruta a acceder el usuario debe estar logueado o incluso a rutas como el login para que lo redireccione al home en caso de estar logueado. Te lo super recomiendo!!
Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo https://www.codigocorrecto.com/programacion/angular-2020-como-usar-guard-canactivate-ejemplo-de-uso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opcion que tenés es que en el constructor del Login, verifiques si hay algun dato almacenado en el sessionStorage (que sea valido para loguearte), y en caso de existir ese dato, uses el Router y te redireccione al inicio.

Ejemplo:
(debes importar el Router)

```
constructor(private router:Router){
    const user= sessionStorage.getItem('user');
    if(user) this.router.navigate(['/inicio']);
}
```